# Joomla's controller ajax request

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Good day:

I'm trying to create a custom component with a controller that accepts Ajax Post (In the backend). My controller structure is as follows:

```
 [06:45 AM]-[vagrant@joomlatools]-

[/var/www/tstack/administrator/components/com_oauth_manager/controllers]     

$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 501 dialout  204 Feb 14 06:21 ./
drwxrwxrwx 17 501 dialout  578 Feb 12 06:26 ../ 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501 dialout   26 Feb 12 06:24 index.html*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501 dialout  652 Feb 13 05:29 oauthserver.php*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501 dialout  919 Feb 14 06:42 oauthservers.json.php*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501 dialout 2428 Feb 14 06:00 oauthservers.php*
```

My javascript code is making a request against `oauthservers.json.php`:

```
 'index.php/?option=com_oauth_manager&task=oauthservers.graphql&format=json'
```

However, I'm getting this error from my console:

```
 Error
 An error has occurred.
 403 You are not authorised to view this resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the fact that I'm using Relay's Network object that requires Node's fetch. The fetch method needs to be specified with a `credential` property. Essentially the value has to be `credentials: 'same-origin'` or else fetch will not send browser cookie apart of the request; the browser cookie is used by Joomla's backend to signify a logged in user. If that cookie isn't present, Joomla assumes you're not logged in and hence, the 403 response.